# Android detect if any key is pressed on soft input

Tags: android

Hi i'm wanting to run a function everytime the user enters anything on the keyboard so i need to detect if the keyboard has been touched and then run the function. I know how to detect individual buttons like done/next etc but is there a way to detect if any button has been pressed?

Comment: you want this in background or within your app?

Comment: @Metalhead1247 within the app essential i have lots of EditText i need to check have content in and it need s to run that check when

Comment: but why do you want to know which key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

```
   edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged start :"+start +"  end :"+count);}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
        Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged start :"+start +"  after :"+after);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChange last char"+s);
    }

});
```